# ExternalUrlException in Laravel5 and Codeception

Tags: api, laravel-5, codeception

I am getting the following error when try to test API in laravel using Codeception. I am accessing an external URL for API.

`[ExternalUrlException] Codeception\Module\Laravel5 can't open external URL:`

How I can fix this issue.

Comment: Laravel5 module tests a local code base, not remote webservice.
If you want to test a remote webservice, use PhpBrowser module instead.

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 3):

instead of putting http://xxx:8000/api/v1, use `api/v1` for the url value instead.

Example:

```
actor: WapiTester
modules:
    enabled:
        - REST:
            url: api/v1
            depends: Laravel5
        - \Helper\Wapi
```